# Unicity of non-equality proofs

Tags: coq

If equality is decidable, all proofs of equality are "the same".  I.e. for `nat`:

```
Require Logic.

Goal forall (n m:nat)  (H1 H2: n = m), H1 = H2.
  intros n m H1 H2.
  subst n.
  now rewrite Logic.Eqdep_dec.UIP_refl_nat.
Qed.
```

Can I prove a similar statement for non-equality?

```
Goal forall (n m:nat)  (H1 H2: n <> m), H1 = H2.
```

---

EDIT: the reason I asked was because I wanted define positive numbers as `nat`s different from 0, and prove that they are equal if their arguments `nat` arguments are equal.

```
Inductive Pos : Set := pos: forall n, n <> 0 -> Pos.
```

Since they also contain a proof term `n <> 0`, one must also show that the proof terms are equal.  But that is apparently impossible (without the addition of an additional axiom) because the proof term is a function.  @Arthur's suggestion to use a boolean predicate is perfect here.

```
Inductive Pos : Set := pos: forall n, n =? 0 = false -> Pos.
```

It is perfect because now the proof term is an equality constraint (an inductive type) and not a function that cannot be proven equal. So below both `H1` and `H2` are equal to `eq_refl`.

```
Definition p2n (p:Pos) := let (n, H) := p in n.

Goal forall p1 p2, p2n p1 = p2n p2 -> p1 = p2.

  destruct p1 as [[|n1] H1], p2 as [[|n2] H2];
    simpl in *; try congruence.
  rewrite (Logic.Eqdep_dec.UIP_refl_bool _ H1).
  rewrite (Logic.Eqdep_dec.UIP_refl_bool _ H2).
  now inversion 1.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `H1` and `H2` are functions, you need the functional extensionality axiom to prove that two such functions are equal.

```
From Coq Require Import FunctionalExtensionality.

Goal forall (n m:nat) (H1 H2: n <> m), H1 = H2.
Proof.
  unfold not; intros n m H1 H2.
  apply functional_extensionality; intros H.
  contradiction (H1 H).
Qed.
```

Interestingly enough, one does not need `UIP_refl_nat` in this case.

You might want to check out [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49780370/2747511) which shows that one should be careful when choosing representations.

Comment: Ok, but the goal is essentially a reduced `FunctionalExtensionality`, so one could just as well just pose the goal as an axiom then, to assume less.  I was thinking that since the functions H1 and H2 are constant functions - they always return `False` - one could somehow use that...

Comment: You can return `False` in many ways, so definitional equality would fail. E.g. let's assume `Variable f : unit -> unit.`, then this fails `Check eq_refl : f = (fun u : unit => f tt).`

Comment: @larsr It is worth remembering that, in practice, types that satisfy UIP also have decidable equality. So you can also replace proofs of `x <> y` with proofs of `(x == y) = false`, which are irrelevant because equality on booleans is irrelevant. (I've used `==` to denote decidable equality.)

Comment: Arthur has provided a very good point! The mathcomp library uses this fact a lot.